# How to design a comment box similar to facebook using only CSS?

Tags: css

I want to implement a comment box similar to facebook using only CSS. I want a small image of the user that is commenting and the comment by the similar.

I tried searching for various CSS, but unable to find something similar to facebook.

Please assist.

Comment: You'll have to explain a bit better than that. So you want a similar design? With an image of the commenter to the left, and the text to the right? There are probably a few hundred different ways to achieve this, try using CSS floats on two divs (one with the image, and one with text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the comment system from Facebook...
Simple to install and you can even manage the comments...

Read more about it here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: but am designing an application from scratch using cakephp. I already have a self-designed comment box, but I want to try and follow similarly using css only.

Comment: @Dwayne,  good luck with that.  If Facebook can't make their comment box work with CSS only, how can you?